# Can I manually speed up convection?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

Let's say, I have half bucket of boiling water and I have added equal amount of freeze cold water to it. I want to have equilibrium temperature reached as quick as possible. Can I speed up the convection manually? Does manually mixing different levels of water work?

Comment: This seems awfully close to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon

Comment: Mix it, with a spoon or something.  That's the fastest.

Comment: [This answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/5510/72446) might be relevant to you.

Answer (score 6):

Unless I'm missing something here, you can speed up reaching the equilibrium temperature simply by stirring the water mixture.

Better still, pour in the cold water from a height so it produces turbulent currents as the hot and cold water mix.