# Which will dry faster?

Tags: thermodynamics, home-experiment

Assume that you have a wet shirt that you have just washed. You squeeze of the surplus water that can be squeezed out.

Method 1:

1)You iron the shirt for 5 minutes and then hang it out to dry out in the warm sunshine (morning sun) for 15 minutes and examine it.

Method 2:

2)You first hang it out in the sunshine for 15 minutes and then iron the shirt for 5 minutes (same heat setting) and then you examine it

Which of the above two methods is better for drying the shirt faster?

(If you need more data:

1)Assume cotton shirt
2)Assume that the wet shirt is not dripping water
3)Assume ambient temp is at 35 deg Celsius
4)Assume that it is not a windy or a cloudy day)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie If this is not a question on physics, this will not be one as well : http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5265/

Comment: @JohnRennie: While I can't say I *like* this question, questions essentially about rates of evaporation seem to be technically physics to me.

Comment: This question definitely sounds like a homework, so it should remain closed, since there is no manifestation that you tried to understand the homework you proposed.