# When a cantilever is subject to vibration test at single frequency excited frequency, can it be calculated analytically using formula

Tags: piezoelectric

I have found P=e*eo*V/(kt*d33*t), but this has "P" pressure. I need frequency vs. voltage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have done vibration test and got voltage values at different frequencies, which i want to get analytical match using equation. Frequency VS output Voltage

Comment: this doesn't really help. You have to clarify what those eeoV, ktd33t and P are... We don't know what you have done, what data you got, how you got them, what apparatus you used, what the purpose is, what you are trying to calculate, what have you tried, where you are stuck and to conclude we know pretty much nothing about your problem. Without further clarification (and actually posting a proper question) we can't really help you.

Comment: I have clamped a cantilever on a ground base shaker and excited that a single frequency each time (10 - 3000 Hz) and at every frequency i got a voltage value which i plotted Frequency VS  voltage. LMS data aqusition system was used to get the output. Polytec laser was used to record the feedback. Now, I am trying to simulate that to see the analytical solution,

Comment: please include all relevant information in your question by editing it. Include formulation, equations, measurements and all other relevant information along with any plots you may have and can help people to understand your setup, what you are trying to achieve and how. Please go ahead an have a look at other questions here in Physics SE to see some nicely formatted questions. (Example from a simple search: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon/5510#5510)